# Minimum width of window to the half of the screen size

Tags: swiftui

How I can set the minimum width of the window to the half of the width of the screen size?
The following code does not work
import SwiftUI

```
@main
struct TestUIApp: App {
  var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
      GeometryReader { proxy in
        ContentView()
      }.frame(minWidth: proxy.frame(.local).width*0.5)
    }
  }
}
```

It throws an error:

> Cannot find 'proxy' in scope

I understand that the proxy is outside the scope, but I cannot bind the proxy to the ContentView

Comment: Do you mean you're unable to bind the proxy to `ContentView`, or that you want to avoid it?

Comment: I mean that I am unable to bind the proxy to ContentView